# Tools for retrieving and modifying multi-value attributes in Microsoft ActiveDirectory

Tags: active-directory, scripting

Most attributes in MSAD are single-valued and pose no problem.
I am familiar with the `dsquery user -samid jdoe | dsmod -webpg "http://some.url/"` method. However, some attributes are multi-valued, such as telephone number and webpage. These values can be managed through the Active Directory Users & Computers Microsoft Console (dsa.msc) via the dialogue shown by clicking on the "Other..." button, but I'd really rather script the modifications. It seems to me that dsmod & dsget do not support multi-value retrieval and editing; only the first value of the set seems to be accesible.
  Am I correct? If I am not correct, I would appreciate a syntax example. If I am correct, would you please recommend an alternative scriptable tool that can handle multi-value attributes? The more "official and supported" the tool, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `-webpg` isn't the multivalued list of web pages.  Using the webpage other button in the GUI, that list of websites is call [url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680541%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  To query it:

```
dsquery * "<full dn>" -l  -attr url
test2
test
```

However dsmod doesn't have a way to modify it.  PowerGUI may work, I use [admod](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/admod/).

```
admod -safety 1 -b "full DN" "url:+:test3"
```

Then, I can do the query again and see the new value:

```
dsquery * "<full dn>" -l  -attr url
test3
test2
test
```

You can browse the [full schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to find the LDAP name of other values.

Comment: Thanks, you hit all my main points, and corrected me on distinction between webpg and url attributes. I regret to hear that MS does not have a suitable "official" option, but it looks like the extant third party stuff will be good tools and have good reputations.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at PowerGUI? It's a good at making mass changes to AD since it manipulates powershell under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'd never heard of PowerGUI, havent' quite yet dipped into PowerShell. We're overdue for that, I suppose. We already use Quest's TOAD product and have been happy with that, and I see that PowerGUI is also a Quest product, so now I'm really intrigued.